# How can i define the range (x/y-axis) of my diagram?

Tags: pgfplots

How can i define the range of my diagram?
The x-axis should start from 0-10 and my y-axis should start from -8 to +8!
This means my origin point of my diagram (left corner point) is (-8/0)
Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=13}, grid=both, scale only axis=true,
  width=10cm, height=15cm,xtick={0,1,...,10},ytick={0,1,...,10},xmin=0,ymin=0,ymax=10,xmax=10]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{14mm}{5mm}},only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
2 3 1 100
4 3 2 3
2 7 3 0.75
7 7 4 45
8 5 2   3
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


%colorbar  horizontal
%colormap/bluered,colorbar
%%colorbar  horizontal
%colorbar/width=2cm,
%colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=8}]
%colorbar sampled line]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You already had the options in your example. You can use `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` options, respectively, to tell your axes what are their limits. Obviously, you will have to adapt your `xticks` and `yticks` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={samples=13},
    grid=both,
    scale only axis=true,
    width=10cm,
    height=15cm,
    xtick={0,1,...,10},
    ytick={-8,-7,...,10},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    ]

\addplot[
    scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{14mm}{5mm}},only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
    ]
    table {
    x y color myvalue
    2 3 1 100
    4 3 2 3
    2 7 3 0.75
    7 7 4 45
    8 5 2 3
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: thx best regards from austria :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with an answer you can accept it using the check mark sign to the left of it. You can also upvote good answers by using the upward pointing arrow there.